# How can I create Multiple sites in IIS using Puppet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, puppet, packer, hashicorp

[IIS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk7dd.png)

I need Multiple websites here "Website1", "Website2". How do I achieve that? Would that require multiple site.pp files?
I tried to add multiple site.pp classes in node default but that doesn't seem to help. Sorry for the vague description as I am new to puppet and GCP.

Comment: Only one site manifest applies to each node you are configuring, so no, configuring multiple of anything on a given node does not involve multiple site manifests.

Comment: Details of how you *would* manage multiple sites on the same server depend on the Puppet module you are using for the purpose, but for it to be possible at all, you need a module that is designed to accommodate multiple sites.  I don't know whether you're likely to encounter any other kind in practice (excepting self-made ones), but it an IIS module could be written in a way that makes supporting multiple sites on the same server difficult or even impossible.